# Как сделать 2 Axios запроса для 1 страницы с middleware?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Требуется сделать 2 разных запроса для одной страницы с помощью middleware.
Первое что приходит на ум это что то вроде такого:
(понимаю что 2 `return'-а выглядят довольно стремно.)

export default function ({$axios, req, store, route}) {

```
  if(route.name == "language-tracker-tracking") {

      console.log('111');

      return $axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + route.params.tracking.toLowerCase(), {})
          .then(response => {
              store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });


  }

  if(route.name == "language-tracker-tracking") {

      console.log('222');

      return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_status" , {
         })
        .then(response => {
            store.commit('tracking/setTrackingStatus', response.data.data.tracking_status);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

  }

}
```

Далее смотрим в консоль в Firebug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можем наблюдать на скрине - срабатывает только первый запрос.
(`console.log('111');`)
Вопрос:
Как корректно, c точки зрения синтаксиса и проектирования - релизовать задуманную идею?

Answer (score 0):

"return" завершает выполнение скрипта.

Попробуйте так:

```
export default async function ({$axios, req, store, route}) {
  if(route.name == "language-tracker-tracking") {
    var result = [];

    result[] = await $axios.get(...);
    result[] = await $axios.get(...);

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы полный пример с учетом моей ситуации прописать? Потому что - что то у меня не получается работающее решение прописать корректно..